# Dataset: dynamically selecting all rows of with the nth element of a column

Tags: dataset

Suppose you have a dataset with the following layout:

```
ds=Dataset[{<|"a" -> "x", "b" -> 1|>,
  <|"a" -> "x", "b" -> 1|>,
  <|"a" -> "x", "b" -> 1|>,
  <|"a" -> "y", "b" -> 1|>,
  <|"a" -> "y", "b" -> 1|>,
  <|"a" -> "z", "b" -> 1|>}]
```

how can I select all the rows where column 1 (`"a"`) is of the the i-th value (e.g. `i=2 --> "y"`), e.g. as if I were to be iterating on the list produced by

```
valuesOfA = ds[All, "a"] // Normal // DeleteDuplicates
```

> {"x", "y", "z"}

e.g. I am looking for something like:

```
With[{i = 2}, ds[Select[#a==valuesOfA[[i]]&]]]
```

[image]

but where I do not have to pre define `valuesOfA`.

Comment: How do you know how many `i` there are ? How do you choose the value of i ?

Comment: @SquareOne assume something like iterating via Table, e.g. `Table[ds[Select#a==valuesOfA[[i]]&]],{i,Length@valuesOfA}]` but again having valuesOfA be somehow innately defined

Comment: Sorry i don't get it. In your post, you say you don't want to predefine `valuesOfA`, but how do you know how many values of A there are ? In your comment you say it should be somehow defined. Why can't you set `valuesOfA = ds[All, "a"] // Normal // DeleteDuplicates` ?

Comment: @SquareOne the question is in regards to if there is a builtin selector or iterator so one can iterate over the unique values in a dataset without having to hard code so much.

Comment: The only solution i see is `ds[GroupBy[#a &]]`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use:

```
GroupBy[ds, First][[2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
ds[GroupBy[#["a"] &], Length][Select[# == 2 &]]
```